# Stripe : Error: Received unknown parameter: bank_account[bank_name]

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have been trying to add a `bank_name` to my Stripe Connect user's external account, but I keep getting an error as if I am misreading the documentation on the function.

`Error: Received unknown parameter: bank_account[bank_name]`

The documentation shows that I should be able to access the `bank_name` from the `bank_account` object, but my error is narrowed down to it being null. My `console.log(newValue.externalAccount.bankName)` returns the bankName as expected that was entered, so it isn't null going in. Any idea why I am getting this error?

**Firebase Function:**

```
exports.createStripeAccount = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const previousValue = change.before.data();
    if (newValue.state === "technician" && previousValue.state === "client") {
      try {
        const account_add_response = await stripe.accounts.create(
          {
            type: "custom",
            country: "US",
            requested_capabilities: ["platform_payments"],
            email: newValue.email,
            tos_acceptance: newValue.stripeTosAcceptance,
            business_type: "individual",
            business_profile: {
              url: newValue.socialLinks.linkedin
            },
            individual: {
              first_name: newValue.firstName,
              last_name: newValue.lastName,
              gender: newValue.gender,
              email: newValue.email,
              phone: newValue.phone,
              address: {
                line1: newValue.address.line1,
                line2: newValue.address.line2,
                city: newValue.address.city,
                state: newValue.address.state,
                postal_code: newValue.address.zip,
                country: newValue.address.country
              },
              ssn_last_4: newValue.technician.ssnLast4,
              dob: {
                day: newValue.dob.day,
                month: newValue.dob.month,
                year: newValue.dob.year
              }
            }
          },
          async function(error, account) {
            if (error) {
              return console.error(error);
            } else {
              console.log(
                "Writing account.id " + account.id + " to user DB..."
              );
              console.log("newValue.externalAccount.bankName: " + newValue.externalAccount.bankName)
              const bank_add_response = await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
                account.id,
                {
                  external_account: {
                    object: "bank_account",
                    country: "US",
                    currency: "USD",
                    account_holder_name:
                      newValue.externalAccount.accountHolderName, // Have user input manually, might be different than user's name
                    account_holder_type: "individual",
                    bank_name: newValue.externalAccount.bankName,
                    routing_number: newValue.externalAccount.routingNumber,
                    account_number: newValue.externalAccount.accountNumber
                  }
                },
                function(error, bank_account) {
                  if (error) {
                    return console.error(error);
                  } else {
                    console.log(
                      "Writing bank_account.id " +
                        bank_account.id +
                        " to user DB..."
                    );
                    return admin
                      .firestore()
                      .collection("users")
                      .doc(context.params.userId)
                      .set(
                        {
                          connectId: account.id,
                          externalAccount: {
                            bankAccountId: bank_account.id,
                            bankName: bank_account.bank_name,
                            last4: bank_account.last4,
                          }
                        },
                        { merge: true }
                      );
                  }
                }
              );
            }
          }
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await change.ref.set(
          { error: userFacingMessage(error) },
          { merge: true }
        );
        return reportError(error, { user: context.params.userId });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to stripe, but 2 things seem wrong to me: 1) When adding a bank account, I think `bank_name` is read only; you just want to specify a routing number and account number and stripe figures out the bank name for you (https://stripe.com/docs/ach#verifying)  2) When you are posting new account details you should be tokenizing your input with stripe and then adding the account via the token (see the paragraph below the code block: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#bank-accounts, see also: https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts)

Comment: If you look at Stripe's External Account creation API 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create 
There is no parameter called `bank_name`, it will only support those parameters in specified in the hash 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create#account_create_bank_account-external_account

Comment: Thanks y’all, that makes sense on why the test account I was using was being labeled STRIPE TEST BANK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I misunderstood the purpose of the `bank_name` field. I thought it was for a custom name the user defines about their bank account, like "Doug's Chase Checkings", but it seems that it's auto generated by Stripe and read only.